# TypeScript error TS2305: has no exported member when importing a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-module-resolution

I have 2 TS files then export just functions (no clesses, interfaces, etc), for example:

```
// the-folder/file1.ts
export function func1() { ... };

// the-folder/file2.ts
export function func2() { ... };
```

and I created a barrel `index.ts`:

```
// the-folder/index.ts
export * from "./file1";
export * from "./file2";
```

Now, I wanted to use it in another TS file, simply importing those `func1()` and `func2()`:

```
// different-folder/some-other-file.ts
import { func1, func2 } from "../the-folder";
```

But here I get the error:

> TS2305: Module  has no exported member 'func1'

and same for func2.

What am I missing?

### UPDATE

I created a stackblitz - [and it works there!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-l1ohbx?file=index.ts) But not in the project.

### UPDATE 1

If I change the `import` to:

```
import { func1, func2 } from "../the-folder/index";
```

it works.

Comment: I suspect that `"<folder-path>"` is the issue, but you omitted the value 

Comment: are you sure your pathing is correct? I suggest trying to import directly from the file1.ts and check if that is working

Comment: added folder paths to the question.
It does work when I import separate files.

Comment: My TS version already complains due to the extensions on the exports: `An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing './file1' instead. ts(2691)`

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your comment. What do you mean by "due to extensions on the export"?

Comment: TS wants this: `export * from "./file1.ts";` to be this instead: `export * from "./file1";`, so no `.ts` file extension.

Comment: @alvipeo: By the way, you need to use `@name` in the comments when not addressing the post author if multiple people have commented, otherwise the addressed person will not be notified. You can always add that if uncertain and SO will sometimes just remove it, if it is unnecessary.

Comment: @H.B. sorry, no ".ts" in exports originally. That was a misspelling.

Comment: @alvipeo: Then i see nothing else that could be off. If the error comes from an IDE, maybe the TS language server needs to be restarted (if the IDE has no function for that, restart the IDE). If this is from a `tsc` call that is just odd...

Comment: @H.B. I even tried with `tsc` - same issue... :/ Thanks anyway!
Could it be something with `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @alvipeo: Possibly, you can try to reduce your codebase to a minimal reproducible example, including resetting settings in the config. Maybe you will stumble upon what triggers the issue on the way.